# Displaying a pop-up notification window

Tags: c++, winapi

How do you create a window that pops up from system tray notification area vertically upwards and displays a message? for example - In MSN, it displays it when someone gets online/offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a window with the look you want, and call [AnimateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632669(VS.85).aspx) to get the pop-in effect. AnimateWindow doesn't really like windows with anything except a simple border.

Answer (score 2):

how about this? [Customizable Alert Window](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/dialog-basedapplications/article.php/c15569/)

Comment: I'm looking for the one that pops up from taskbar, maybe I'll figure out of this one.

Comment: No dramas. As suggested by Chris Becke, use the link I sent you to create the notification window, and then call AnimateWindow on that window. You'll get there :)